# Sorting the Map in descending order of values

Tags: java, dictionary, collections

I have been trying to sort the map in descending order of `values` but my existing code is sorting in descending order of `keys`. how do I sort in descending order of values?
My code:

```
System.out.println("Unsorted Map:" +merger);
Map<Integer, Double> Sortedmerger = SortByValue(merger); 
System.out.println("Sorted Map: "+ Sortedmerger);

public static TreeMap<Integer, Double> SortByValue  (Map<Integer, Double> map) {
ValueComparator vc =  new ValueComparator(map);
TreeMap<Integer, Double> sortedMap = new TreeMap<Integer, Double>(Collections.reverseOrder());
        sortedMap.putAll(map);
        return sortedMap;
    }   

class ValueComparator implements Comparator<Double> {

    Map<Integer, Double> map;

    public ValueComparator(Map<Integer, Double> base) {
        this.map = base;
    }

    public int compare(Double a, Double b) {
        if (map.get(a) >= map.get(b)) {
            return -1;
        } else {
            return 1;
        } // returning 0 would merge keys 
    }
}
```

My output:

```
Unsorted Map:{1=0.53, 2=0.48, 23=0.54, 10=0.47}
Sorted Map: {23=0.54, 10=0.47, 2=0.48, 1=0.53}
```

Comment: Use a different data structure, or you could try a custom [`Comparator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html).

Comment: A map is thought to be used to have fast access (here O(log n)) if you have the key and want the value behind it. As @ElliottFrisch suggests you'd better use another data structure.

Comment: Take a look at this [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/109383/how-to-sort-a-mapkey-value-on-the-values-in-java?rq=1) and read the comments there, as well as the comments on the highly upvoted answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your map key type is Integer so you have to use `Comparator<Integer>` and your `compare` method should take integer inputs and by that Integer key you can get Double value by `map.get(a)` and `map.get(b)`. and in `TreeMap` constructor you have to define comparator class which you have created.(i.e ValueComparator)

refer this code:

```
public static TreeMap<Integer, Double> SortByValue(Map<Integer, Double> map) {
        ValueComparator vc =  new ValueComparator(map);
        TreeMap<Integer, Double> sortedMap = new TreeMap<Integer, Double>(vc);\\constructor should be vc which extends Comparator
        sortedMap.putAll(map); 
        return sortedMap;
    }

class ValueComparator implements Comparator<Integer> {

    Map<Integer, Double> map;

    public ValueComparator(Map<Integer, Double> base) {
        this.map = base;
    }

    @Override
    public int compare(Integer a, Integer b) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (map.get(a) >= map.get(b)) {
            return -1;
        } else {
            return 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks similar to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1283722/1441122) to a related question. While it may work in some cases, be aware that it has significant restrictions, which will cause obscure bugs if violated.